# Subclassing multiprocessing.queues.Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subclass

I had this working previously, but after a recent full os update, likely updating my python3 install, what I had working now isn't. I'm basically trying to subclass the `multiprocessing.queue.Queue` class, but I keep getting errors that methods and properties are missing. Here's what used to work:

```py
class q_class(multiprocessing.queues.Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        # ... my own init stuff goes here
        super(q_class, self).__init__(ctx=multiprocessing.get_context())
    def put(self,message):
        # ... my own put stuff goes here
        super(q_class, self).put(message)
    def get(self):
        # ... my own get stuff goes here
        super(q_class, self).get()
    def __getstate__(self):
        multiprocessing.context.assert_spawning(self) #is this necessary?
        return (self._ignore_epipe, self._maxsize, self._reader, self._writer,
                self._rlock, self._wlock, self._sem, self._opid,
                self.report_bottlenecks, self.bottleneck_time, self.debug)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        (self._ignore_epipe, self._maxsize, self._reader, self._writer,
         self._rlock, self._wlock, self._sem, self._opid,
         self.report_bottlenecks, self.bottleneck_time,self.debug) = state
        #self._after_fork() #is this necessary?
```

But when I try to use the `.get()` method I get an error that the `_poll()` method doesn't exist. Peeking at the [SimpleQueue subclass creation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#L362) that is in the multiprocessing source, I see that there at least it was necessary to explicitly define the `_poll()` method, so I tried that (just copied the line linked above to mine), then got an error about `_poll()` needing a timeout value, which is weird because I thought the reader class's `_poll()` had a default as `timeout=None`, but whatever, I solved that by defining a custom method:

```py
    def _poll(self,timeout=.01):
        self._reader._poll(timeout)
```

Which works to get past the timeout error, only now when I try to put a message on the queue I get an error that there is no `_closed` attribute. Looking at the `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#L52) again, this attribute should get created when `self._reset()` is called within its `__init__()`, which should in turn have been called at the end of my subclass' `__init__()`, but clearly it hasn't, so I'm now thinking I must simply misunderstand how to subclass in the first place (or, at least, my understanding has become outdated). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you see that final line that was commented-out?

```
        #self._after_fork() #is this necessary?
```

Yeah, it was necessary. Uncommenting makes the code work.